# hooks in codeigniter version 3

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3 .I have enabled hooks in my hooks file

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'myclass',
        'function' => 'myfunction',
        'filename' => 'myfile.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => ''
);
```

on enabling hooks i am getting the error as

```
`Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`
```

Pls help to resolve the above error. i have enabled drivers and libraries in config file.

this is the code i have used in hooks

```
class Check_login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function CheckLoggin()
    {
        $url = $this->uri->segment(1);
        if($url == "givenparameter")
        {
            $login_id = $this->session->userdata("ID");
            $get_url = $this->uri->segment(2);
            if($login_id == "" && $get_url != 'login')
            {
                redirect('controller/login', 'refresh');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook has a dependency on the session class. So try changing `pre_controller` hooks to `post_controller'` like,

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Myclass',
        'function' => 'Myfunction',
        'filename' => 'Myfile.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => ''
);
```

If not works then try `post_controller_constructor` instead of `post_controller`

Comment: Ya I tried with those things but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks filepath : application/hooks

controller filename : Blocker.php

```
 class Blocker {

    function Blocker(){
    }
    function requestBlocker(){
            echo "done";
    }
}
```

Also, you need to config this.

config path : application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Blocker',
        'function' => 'requestBlocker',
        'filename' => 'Blocker.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => ""
);
```

Also you need to allow hooks in your configurations. ie. application/config/config.php

Comment: I think your second blocker function meaning to be __construct() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Comment: Ya i have tried with the above thing. If I use {extends CI_Controller} i am getting the error `Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php` . can we write by using CI_Model

Comment: Have you configured encryption_key in config file $config['encryption_key'] = 'yourkey';

Comment: for pre controller you have to use above

Comment: @Nobita sorry for late reply ya i have already tried with every option said above, but same error

Comment: check this link for hooks in codeigniter with example https://www.javatpoint.com/codeigniter-hooks

Comment: Yes all those things works fine in version 2 but in version 3 i am getting these errors